# Permission ATTR{idVendor} for USB devices on linux mint to use table mobii protab2 XXL

Tags: android, permissions, usb, adb

I am using linux mint, and consulting [VendorIds](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#VendorIds) from http://developer.android.com I don't know how to detect my tablet device correctly. My tablet device is Mobii protab 2 XXL, fabricated by Point of view.

I have created 50-android.rules at /etc/udev/rules.d/ and added line:
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb|usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}==”0955″, MODE=”0666″`

But adb devices throw:

```
List of devices attached  ????????????  no permissions
```

Does anyone know which idvendor do I have to use???

usb:

```
    lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1058:1003 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 1a34:0203  
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 06f8:3008 Guillemot Corp. 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 18d1:0003 Google Inc.
```

And I put in udev last time:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1:0003", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"
```

It worked the first time, but when I restart the PC, the permissions are denied. I have tried to restart:

```
sudo service udev restart
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

But it didn't work.

NOTE:

Some devices don't work propertly doing this process. If you still having problems, try execute

```
sudo adb start-server
```

It works with Point of view device.

Comment: if the udev rule is being picked up at boot you shouldn't have to reboot the service. When you change a rule you need to restart the service, possibly remove the device and plug it back in again, or reboot the pc. Are you sure you are in the plugdev group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On 51-android.rules:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`, `ATTRS{idVendor}=="18b1"`, `ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003"`, `MODE="0666"`.

And use chmod command to have permission 666 (the number of the beast, muahahhaha) on adb or will not work.

Good luck.

Comment: Now is working fine when i restart the computer all time, thks

Answer (score 5):

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", 
ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX",
MODE="0660", 
OWNER="`<your user name>`"
```

and try using upper case and lower case because in linux a lot of people are having problems to add permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Following from the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android) page I would create /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18D1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="18D1",ATTR{idProduct}=="0003",SYMLINK+="android_adb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="18D1",ATTR{idProduct}=="0003",SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"
```

Then as root run `udevadm control --reload-rules`
You may need to replace 18D1 with 18d1. That is what I have done and it works great. You don't necessarily need the username as long as you give permission (MODE="0666") to everyone. If you require more security look at adding the OWNER tag. Again these are rules that I have used on Arch, they *should* work on Mint.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

- **Connect your device.**
- **Run `lsusb`.**
- **Disconnect your device and run it again.**
- **Find your device hex by comparing both lsusb results:**
  `Bus 001 Device 013: ID xxxx:2765` and note the `xxxx`
- **Create a new rule:**
  `sudo nano /tmp/android.rules`
- **Insert:**
  `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", MODE="0666"`
- **Copy the rule:**
  `sudo cp /tmp/android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
- **Change permissions:**
  `sudo chmod 644   /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
  `sudo chown root. /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
- **Retstart ADB:**
  `sudo service udev restart`
  `sudo killall adb`
- **Reconnect your device.**
- **Test ADB:** `adb devices`
  `List of devices attached`
  `xyzxyzxyz  device`

**Source:** [pts.blog: How to fix the adb no permissions error on Ubuntu Lucid](http://ptspts.blogspot.ch/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html)

Comment: I thought I could use this same setting with the emulator, but it seems that adb does not recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Ethan, look at "lsusb" to locate the Mobii vendor ID. In the example below, **046d** is the ID for Logitech. "0955" belongs to nVidia.

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

Also, don't forget to restart udev after you've changed the 50-android.rules file.

Comment: I use sudo service udev restart, and with lsusb i put the ID XXXX, and dont work

Comment: What ID did you use? XXXX doesn't really help us diagnose or verify that your number is correct. Can you show us the output from lsusb?

Comment: Definitely split your idVendor: ATTR{idVendor}=="18D1",ATTR{idProduct}=="0003". I've also seen some funny behavior when adb fails and I kill-server. If I don't turn off app debugging on my phone and turn it back on it just won't work. adb on my phone was the cause, not the PC.